# refresh materialized view every 26th of the month in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a materialized view temp_mv based on table temp.I want to refresh this materialized view every month on 26th.Please suggest.

syntex is:

```
Create Materialized view temp_mv
refresh complete start with (sysdate) next  (sysdate+1/1440) with rowid
as select * from temp;
```

This materialized view refresh on every minute.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Create Materialized view temp_mv
refresh complete start with (sysdate) next (add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),1)+25)+0.5/24 with rowid
as select * from temp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your info If i want to run this on every 26th of the month at 00:30 AM ...What i need to add.i have tried to add like below but its not working .  Create Materialized view temp_mv
refresh complete start with to_date(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') next to_date(((add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),1)+25)||' 00:30:00'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') with rowid
as select * from temp;   its shows me below error:  ORA-23420 interval must evaluate to a time in the future
Please assist

Comment: i've edited my answer to run at 00:30 on the 26th day of next month